# Why comments counting wrong?

Tags: mysql

I need count comments and votes for project, but comments counts wrongly.

```
   SELECT projects . * , COUNT( votes.project_id ) AS votes, COUNT( comments.user_id) AS comments
    FROM  `projects` 
    LEFT JOIN  `votes` ON  `projects`.`id` =  `votes`.`project_id` 
    LEFT JOIN  `comments` ON  `projects`.`id` =  `comments`.`project_id` 
    WHERE  `votes`.`created_at` >  '2014-05-31 20:21:43' AND 
    GROUP BY  `projects`.`id` 
    ORDER BY  `votes` DESC
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CcRo5JC.png]

[image]

Output:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aCUZETO.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count is "wrong" because the `COUNT()` aggregate is counting rows in the resultset, not rows from the individual tables.  If you had two rows with `project_id = 1` in the `comments` table, the two count aggregates would both return 8.

Basically, each row from `comments` is being matched with each row from `projects`.

There's several approaches to working around this problem. One is to use a subselect in the SELECT list, though this can expensive (in terms of performance) for large sets:

```
SELECT p.*
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM votes v
          WHERE v.project_id = p.project_id
            AND v.created_at > '2014-05-31 20:21:43'
       ) AS votes
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM comments c
          WHERE c.project_id = p.project_id
       ) AS comment_cnt
  FROM projects p
HAVING votes > 0
 ORDER BY votes DESC
```

(The HAVING clause is included to emulate the original query; in the original, the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN to the votes table is negated b by the predicate on `votes.created_at` in the WHERE clause.)

---

Another approach is to get the count from each of the tables separately (get the count by project_id in two separate queries, referenced as inline views, and then combine those counts with JOIN operations. For example:

```
SELECT p.*
     , w.votes
     , IFNULL(d.comment_cnt,0) AS comment_cnt
  FROM projects p
  JOIN ( SELECT v.project_id
              , COUNT(1) AS votes
           FROM votes v
          WHERE v.created_at > '2014-05-31 20:21:43'
          GROUP BY v.project_id
       ) w
    ON w.project_id = p.project_id
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT c.project_id
               , COUNT(1) AS comment_cnt
           FROM comments c
          GROUP BY c.project_id
       ) d
    ON d.project_id = p.project_id
 ORDER BY w.votes DESC
```

(Because the specification was to return only rows that had a "votes" count greater than zero, we can use an INNER JOIN to exclude rows that don't have any "votes". For the comment count, we use an OUTER JOIN, and simply replace any NULL values with zeros.

There are other approaches too.

Performance is going to depend on the number of rows, cardinality of referenced columns, available indexes, execution plan chosen by the optimizer, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to count distinct values, so something a little like:

```
SELECT projects . * , COUNT( DISTINCT votes.user_id ) AS votes, COUNT( DISTINCT comments.user_id) AS comments
FROM  `projects` 
LEFT JOIN  `votes` ON  `projects`.`id` =  `votes`.`project_id` 
LEFT JOIN  `comments` ON  `projects`.`id` =  `comments`.`project_id` 
WHERE  `votes`.`created_at` >  '2014-05-31 20:21:43' AND 
GROUP BY  `projects`.`id` 
ORDER BY  `votes` DESC
```